# Android Proguard using getting signin apk Errors

Tags: android, proguard

Why this error comming,how to solve this,,anyone give default proguard rules have send me..

Note: there were 3 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
Note: there were 22 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Thread(Tasks limiter_1): destruction
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

  > Job failed, see logs for details
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 57s
23 actionable tasks: 22 executed, 1 up-to-date

Answer (score 0):

If you see details in your error log you will get the missing library.
I have added below line in progourd.cfg for my project for a similar type of error while generating signed apk.

-dontwarn com.google.**